# Combining overlapping dates by ID based on a condition

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr

I would like to select start and end dates for each ID based on a condition.

For each ID, if the difference between the end date and start date is <=14 days then I would like to take the end date for that row and take the start date from the row above. Ie. combine time periods for intervals less than 14 days.

I have been able to do this for the ID's 45 and 28, but not for 81, which has several dates which are less than 14 days.

I have attached my data and what I hope to end up with.

```
ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     Difference  
45  2004-09-04  2004-10-09  NA
45  2004-11-04  2004-12-08  26      
28  2013-07-25  2013-08-28  NA      
28  2013-08-27  2017-04-06  -1
81  2013-02-22  2013-03-28  NA
81  2013-03-25  2013-04-26  -3
81  2013-04-24  2013-05-26  -2
81  2013-05-22  2013-06-23  -4
81  2013-06-24  2013-07-26  1
81  2013-07-22  2013-08-23  -4


ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     Difference      startdate     enddate
45  2004-09-04  2004-10-09    NA            2004-09-04  2004-10-09
45  2004-11-04  2004-12-08    26            2004-11-04  2004-12-08
28  2013-08-27  2017-04-06    -1            2013-07-25  2017-04-06
81  2013-07-22  2013-08-23    -4            2013-02-22  2013-08-23
```

new data sample

```
ID  START_DATE  end.date.plus   end.date    start.date  
75  18/10/11    21/11/11    1/01/70 1/01/70  
46  2/10/09     8/08/10     1/01/70 1/01/70  
45  4/09/04     9/10/04     1/01/70 1/01/70  
45  4/11/04     8/12/04     1/01/70 1/01/70  
28  25/07/13    28/08/13    1/01/70 1/01/70  
28  27/08/13    6/04/17     1/01/70 1/01/70  
81  22/02/13    28/03/13    1/01/70 1/01/70  
81  25/03/13    26/04/13    1/01/70 1/01/70  
81  24/04/13    26/05/13    1/01/70 1/01/70  
81  22/05/13    23/06/13    1/01/70 1/01/70  
81  24/06/13    26/07/13    1/01/70 1/01/70  
81  22/07/13    23/08/13    1/01/70 1/01/70
```

Comment: Why do you keep the row where `ID` == 45 and `Difference` == NA but not the other rows with `Difference` == NA?

Comment: Because the difference between the rows for ID 45 is >= 14 days.

Comment: If the difference is >= 14 days, I don't want to combine the time periods (overlapping periods).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the below function that calculates the structure of the groups by ID (*the column Difference, I keep it in the data frame, however, it is irrelevant*). Firstly, using your example;

```
data <- read.table(text=
                  "ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     Difference  
                   45  2004-09-04  2004-10-09  NA
                   45  2004-11-04  2004-12-08  26      
                   28  2013-07-25  2013-08-28  NA      
                   28  2013-08-27  2017-04-06  -1
                   81  2013-02-22  2013-03-28  NA
                   81  2013-03-25  2013-04-26  -3
                   81  2013-04-24  2013-05-26  -2
                   81  2013-05-22  2013-06-23  -4
                   81  2013-06-24  2013-07-26  1
                   81  2013-07-22  2013-08-23  -4", header=T)

continuum <- function(data){
  library(parsedate, quietly=T) #access to parse_date() function for automatic recognition of date format
  data[,c("STARTDATE", "ENDDATE")] <- lapply(data[,c("STARTDATE", "ENDDATE")], function(e) as.Date(parse_date(e)))
  data <- data[with(data, order(ID, STARTDATE)),]
  data$diffr <- 0
  result <- data.frame()
  for ( i in unique(data$ID)){
    temp <-data[data$ID==i,]
    if(length(temp$ID)==1){
      startdate <- temp$STARTDATE
      enddate <- temp$ENDDATE
    } else{
    for(j in 1:(length(temp$ID)-1)){
      temp$diffr[j+1] <- difftime(temp$STARTDATE[j+1], temp$ENDDATE[j])
    }
    startdate <- c(temp$STARTDATE[temp$diffr==0], temp$STARTDATE[temp$diffr>14])
      if(identical(rep(TRUE, length(temp$ID)), temp$diffr<=14)){
        enddate <- max(temp$ENDDATE)
      } else{
        enddate <- c(temp$ENDDATE[match(temp$ENDDATE[temp$diffr>14], temp$ENDDATE)-1], temp$ENDDATE[length(temp$diffr)])
      }
      } 
    result <- rbind(result, 
                    data.frame(
                      ID=rep(i, length(startdate)),
                      startdate=startdate,
                      enddate=enddate))
  }
  return(result)
}

continuum(data)
#  ID  startdate    enddate
#1 28 2013-07-25 2017-04-06
#2 45 2004-09-04 2004-10-09
#3 45 2004-11-04 2004-12-08
#4 81 2013-02-22 2013-08-23
```

Secondly, on a bit more complicated example:

```
data2 <- read.table(text=
                  "ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     Difference  
                   45  2004-09-04  2004-10-09  NA
                   45  2004-11-04  2004-12-08  26      
                   28  2013-07-25  2013-08-28  NA      
                   28  2013-08-27  2017-04-06  -1
                   81  2013-02-22  2013-03-28  NA
                   81  2013-03-25  2013-04-26  -3
                   81  2013-04-24  2013-05-26  -2
                   81  2013-05-22  2013-06-23  -4
                   81  2013-06-24  2013-07-26  1
                   81  2013-07-22  2013-08-23  -4
                   81  2014-05-01  2015-06-02  8 
                   81  2015-07-05  2015-09-06  9", header=T)
continuum(data2)
#  ID  startdate    enddate
#1 28 2013-07-25 2017-04-06
#2 45 2004-09-04 2004-10-09
#3 45 2004-11-04 2004-12-08
#4 81 2013-02-22 2013-08-23
#5 81 2014-05-01 2015-06-02
#6 81 2015-07-05 2015-09-06
```

EDIT: The function was adjusted, it automatically recognizes the date format (at least the formats you provided so far, not claiming it will recognize jibberish). Now follows your new, more elaborate example:

```
data3 <- read.table(text="
                    ID START_DATE end.date.plus end.date start.date
                    75 18/10/11 21/11/11 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    46 2/10/09 8/08/10 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    45 4/09/04 9/10/04 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    45 4/11/04 8/12/04 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    28 25/07/13 28/08/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    28 27/08/13 6/04/17 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    81 22/02/13 28/03/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    81 25/03/13 26/04/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    81 24/04/13 26/05/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    81 22/05/13 23/06/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    81 24/06/13 26/07/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
                    81 22/07/13 23/08/13 1/01/70 1/01/70", header=T)
```

This data set is different from the previous example, not only in regards to the date format, and that is why the function did not work. It is also a more robust example, better example, as you cover more case of the behavior of the two dates, like the instance of the ID 45, the situation is new (one sub-continuum hid by the longer one), not occurring in the example before. That makes also the function more robust! What you need to do next is to provide the correct names of variables for the function, `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE`. I figure that `end.date` and `start.date` are dummies, that is why I convert `START_DATE` into `STARTDATE` and `end.date.plus` to `ENDDATE`, as this logic was set at asking your question.

```
names(data3)[2] <- "STARTDATE"
names(data3)[3] <- "ENDDATE"
```

You can rename the columns, load the function from above and apply it on data set `data3`:

```
continuum(data3)
```

which prints

```
 #  ID  startdate    enddate
 #1 28 2013-07-25 2017-06-04
 #2 45 2004-04-09 2004-09-10
 #3 46 2009-02-10 2010-08-08
 #4 75 2011-10-18 2011-11-21
 #5 81 2013-02-22 2013-08-23
```

EDIT2: I created myself a complex example of dates and made the following function:

```
continuum <- function(data){
  data <- data[with(data, order(ID, STARTDATE)),]
  result <- data.frame()
  for ( i in unique(data$ID)){
    temp <-data[data$ID==i,]
    j <- 1
    startdate <- temp$STARTDATE[1]
    enddate <- temp$ENDDATE[1]
    if(length(temp$ID)==1){result <- rbind(result, data.frame(ID=i, STARTDATE=startdate, ENDDATE=enddate))
    } else 
      while(j < length(temp$ID)){
        if(temp$STARTDATE[j+1]-14<=temp$ENDDATE[j]){ 
          startdate <- startdate
          if(temp$ENDDATE[j+1]<=enddate){enddate <- enddate} else{enddate <- temp$ENDDATE[j+1]}
          if(j==(length(temp$ID)-1)){result <- rbind(result, data.frame(ID=i, STARTDATE=startdate, ENDDATE=enddate))}
          j <- j+1
        } else if(temp$STARTDATE[j+1]-14>enddate){
          result <- rbind(result, data.frame(ID=i, STARTDATE=startdate, ENDDATE=enddate))
          startdate <- temp$STARTDATE[j+1]
          enddate <- temp$ENDDATE[j+1]
          if(j==(length(temp$ID)-1)){result <- rbind(result, data.frame(ID=i, STARTDATE=startdate, ENDDATE=enddate))}
          j <- j+1 
        } else{
          if(temp$ENDDATE[j+1]<=enddate){enddate <- enddate} else{enddate <- temp$ENDDATE[j+1]}
          if(j==(length(temp$ID)-1)){result <- rbind(result, data.frame(ID=i, STARTDATE=startdate, ENDDATE=enddate))}
          j <- j+1}
      }
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Make sure that you the dates are correctly interpreted by R! Dates like this

```
45 4/11/04 8/12/04 1/01/70 1/01/70 
28 25/07/13 28/08/13 1/01/70 1/01/70
```

are not in a good date format, better, go for a format like `2017-04-23`,

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi Patrik, Thank you for your response. I have a few simple questions -

Comment: As I have the data n a dataframe already, can I just substitute the name of the data frame into  "data"?

Comment: Also, I have already loaded dlpyr, therefore can I omit - "library(dplyr, quietly = T)".

Comment: Where you have -   "result <- data.frame()" do I need to insert my "data.frame". Sorry for these simple questions, but I couldn't get your code to work, so I suspected it was one of these issues.

Comment: for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$overlap[i]==TRUE){
    df$startdate[i]<-aggregate(df$STARTDATE[i], by=list(df$ ID[i]),min)
    df$enddate[i]<-aggregate(df$ENDDATE[i], by=list(df$ID[i]),max)
  }
}
  This returns the error    Error in as.Date.default(value) : 
  do not know how to convert 'value' to class “Date”

Comment: Hi, if you already loaded it, it doesn't need to be loaded the second time, I would though keep it there if one forgets to load dplyr beforehand. You can feed in the name of the existing data frame, just rename the `result` into what you need but it need to enter the function as an empty data frame.

Comment: The function work on the sample data frame you provided. This means there is something different in the data you are applying it on. Can you post a sample from data to which you are applying the function? Put it into EDIT: new data sample into your question pls. Lastly, the error you get is bcs you did not convert the variable START_DATE into R dates.

Comment: Pls note, I removed the dependency on dplyr in the function

Comment: This is the error I get      > continuum(data)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "diffr", value = c(0, NA)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
Called from: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "diffr", value = c(0, NA))
Browse[1]>

Comment: It says that your column diffr contains NAs. This is not possible in my case as I explicitly say `data$diffr <- 0`. Pls remember, do not adjust the function that I provided, load it as it is above, and, pls provide the data you are working on so we make it work for you.

Comment: I see new sample, good, I see the problem already will update me answer with new sample and solution to it

Comment: Thank you Patrik. Unfortunately I am still getting an errorr   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "diffr", value = c(0, NA)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
Called from: `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "diffr", value = c(0, NA))
Browse[1]> c

Comment: See the edit, hope this works for you, if not get back to me, I find this problem very intriguing

Comment: Thank you. This is the error I have got      Error in data.frame(ID = rep(i, length(startdate)), startdate = startdate,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
Called from: data.frame(ID = rep(i, length(startdate)), startdate = startdate, 
    enddate = enddate)

Comment: I just read your comment about the dates - actually the date format is incorrect, as it converted when I opened the csv file in excel. Sorry! I am not sure if there is a way to copy the columns directly from the R dataframe ?

Comment: Apologies - the format is as I originally posted "%Y-%m-%d"

Comment: That format should be fine, it is handled by the `parse_date()`, so there must be another issue not occurring in the examples that I could not expect. The best would be to upload your dataset online and provide me the link (remove all that is sensitive and only leave the dates with IDs). I will take a look at the errors.

Comment: Is it helpful if I put a larger sample up?

Comment: Definitely helpful

Comment: Posted an update (EDIT2). I created a complex example myself which helped me to rebuild the function. Check it out and let me know it it worked on your data.